# Setting table column width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got a simple table that is used for an inbox as follows:

```
<table border="1">
     <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I set the width so the From and Date are 15% of the page width and the Subject is 70%. I also want the table to take up the whole page width.

Answer (score 545, accepted):

You can set the width of a table column using the [**CSS `width` property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) of the [**`col` element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col). The width value is most commonly specified in pixels (`width: 200px;`), or as a percentage of the width of the parent element (`width: 50%;`). Example with inline `style` attribute:

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
    <colgroup>
       <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 70%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    </colgroup>
    
    
    
    <!-- Put <thead>, <tbody>, and <tr>'s here! -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #777">15%</td>
            <td style="background-color: #aaa">70%</td>
            <td style="background-color: #777">15%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where should this be placed in the DOM relative to the <thead> or <table> elements?

Comment: Like the cleanliness of this solution. However, please close out the col e.g
<col span="1" style="width: 15%;" /> or
<col span="1" style="width: 15%;"></col>

Comment: @Isu_guy you only close <col> when using XHTML -- in HTML, <col> tag has no closing... see [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp) for more info. In HTML5, <col> is a void element, meaning it [MUST NOT be closed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/col.html)

Comment: @Zulu according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_col_width.asp "The <col> width attribute is not supported in HTML5."

Comment: @Matija Its optional.  "Optionally, a "/" character, which may be present only if the element is a void element."

Comment: @JohnGietzen to clarify: you may use "<col .... />" syntax in HTML5 (although it's deprecated), but NOT closing tag syntax ("<col ....></col>") - [Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element)

Comment: @MatijaNalis Ah, yes, I didn't see that he has used `</col>`.

Comment: @Caltor: the code is **not** using the <col> `width attribute`; it is using a `CSS *style* width`, which is what replaced the <col> width attribute. (despite the multiple people up-voting that comment!!)

Comment: `span="1"` is superfluous since 1 is the default.

Comment: As noted in another answer you may need to add `table-layout:fixed` to the CSS for the table.  See also https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Comment: Best practice is to keep your HTML for structure and semantics and CSS for presentation, avoiding use of the `style` attribute in HTML elements.

Comment: Here's a good way to waste 10 minutes: Use this solution and observe it not work at all as your table keeps making the columns however long it feels like. The question asks how to set a width - not suggest a width and hope for the best like this answer does!

Comment: a good rule of thumb is you leave the last column without value because it will eat up the remaining space. it would act as a fail safe. this way you wouldn't bother math-ing if they really summed up to 100%. just make sure that your table width is 100%.

Answer (score 172):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
th.from, th.date {
  width: 15%
}
th.subject {
  width: 70%; /* Not necessary, since only 70% width remains */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="from">From</th>
      <th class="subject">Subject</th>
      <th class="date">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>[from]</td>
      <td>[subject]</td>
      <td>[date]</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The best practice is to keep your `HTML` and `CSS` separate for less code duplication, and for separation of concerns (`HTML` for structure and semantics, and `CSS` for presentation).

Note that, for this to work in older versions of Internet Explorer, you may have to give your table a specific width (e.g., 900px). That browser has some problems rendering an element with percentage dimensions if its wrapper doesn't have exact dimensions.

Comment: this solution fails if you have colspans in the first row

Comment: Good because <col width=""> is obsolete in HTML5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col

Comment: I had to use min-width.

Comment: I had to use `min-width` instead of `width` for it to work, but overall great, thanks.

Answer (score 42):

Use the CSS below, the first declaration will ensure your table sticks to the widths you provide (you'll need to add the classes in your HTML):

```
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
th.from, th.date {
  width: 15%;
}
th.subject{
  width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Actually you only need to specify width of the two columns. The third one will be calculated automatically, so `table{table-layout:fixed};.from,.date{width:15%}` is enough. Unless the classes are used on other elements too, writing `th.from` is redundant and can be shortened to just `.from`.

Comment: Oh my, this `table-layout: fixed` is a real gotcha! This answer should really be higher up.

Answer (score 19):

Alternative way with just one class while keeping your styles in a CSS file, which even works in IE7:

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<style>
    .mytable td, .mytable th { width:15%; }
    .mytable td + td, .mytable th + th { width:70%; }
    .mytable td + td + td, .mytable th + th + th { width:15%; }
</style>
```

More recently, you can also use the `nth-child()` selector from CSS3 (IE9+), where you'd just put the nr. of the respective column into the parenthesis instead of stringing them together with the adjacent selector. Like this, for example:

```
<style>
    .mytable tr > *:nth-child(1) { width:15%; }
    .mytable tr > *:nth-child(2) { width:70%; }
    .mytable tr > *:nth-child(3) { width:15%; }
</style>
```

Comment: The proposed `:nth-child` solution is horrible in terms of performance. There is no valid reason to use it (especially with the universal selector) in this example where there are only three elements (`th` or `col`) to style. Additionally, you only need to set width to the `th` in the first row. The `.mytable td` in the first example is redundant.

Comment: "The proposed :nth-child solution is horrible in terms of performance." - citation needed.

Comment: This should be enough: [Efficiently
Rendering CSS](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/). With your use of the universal selector the browser will first check ALL elements whether they are nth child of another element, then if their direct parent is `tr` and then whether they belong to `.mytable`. If you really want to use "nth" then something like this will probably be much better: `.mytable th:nth-of-type(1) {width: 15%}; .mytable th:nth-of-type(2) {width: 70%};`. There is also no need to specify the third column width in this case.

Comment: Personally I would use classes or just `.mytable th+th{width: 70%}.mytable th+th+th{width:15%}`. The "nth" selectors themselves may be very useful but in this particular case (a tiny table with only 3 columns) are not really needed. When using `table-layout: fixed` you can even do just this: `table{table-layout:fixed}th:first-child+th{width:70%}`.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But those articles are from years back, and there are bigger problems today that CSS selectors, like huge amounts of images and JS code.

Comment: That is definitely true but abusing CSS3 selectors does have negative performance impact, especially on large and complicated sites. I would use them only if there is no simple alternative.

Answer (score 15):

These are my two suggestions.

1. Using classes. There is no need to specify width of the two other columns as they will be set to 15% each automatically by the browser.

   ```css
       table { table-layout: fixed; }
       .subject { width: 70%; }
   ```

   ```html
       <table>
         <tr>
           <th>From</th>
           <th class="subject">Subject</th>
           <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
   ```
2. Without using classes. Three different methods but the result is identical.

   a)

   ```css
       table { table-layout: fixed; }
       th+th { width: 70%; }
       th+th+th { width: 15%; }
   ```

   ```html
       <table>
         <tr>
           <th>From</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
           <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
   ```

   b)

   ```css
       table { table-layout: fixed; }
       th:nth-of-type(2) { width: 70%; }
   ```

   ```html
       <table>
         <tr>
           <th>From</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
           <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
   ```

   c) This one is my favourite. Same as b) but with better browser support.

   ```css
       table { table-layout: fixed; }
       th:first-child+th { width: 70%; }
   ```

   ```html
       <table>
         <tr>
           <th>From</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
           <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Add `colgroup` after your `table` tag. Define `width` and number of columns here, and add the `tbody` tag. Put your `tr` inside of `tbody`.

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
       <col span="1" style="width: 30%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 70%;">
    </colgroup>
    
    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>First column</td>
            <td>Second column</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your body (or the div which is wrapping your table) 'settings' you should be able to do this:

```
body {
  width: 98%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}


th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


th.From, th.Date {
  width: 15%;
}

th.Date {
  width: 70%;
}


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="From">From</th>
      <th class="Subject">Subject</th>
      <th class="Date">Date</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Me</td>
       <td>Your question</td>
       <td>5/30/2009 2:41:40 AM UTC</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/oxogu)

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 20%">
           column 1
        </th>
        <th style="width: 40%">
           column 2
        </th>
        <th style="width: 40%">
           column 3
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20%">
           value 1
        </td>
        <td style="width: 40%">
           value 2
        </td>
        <td style="width: 40%">
           value 3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
    table { table-layout: fixed; }
    .subject { width: 70%; }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th class="subject">Subject</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another minimal way to do it in CSS that works even in older browsers that do not support `:nth-child` and the like selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/3wZWt/.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dmitriy</td>
        <td>Learning CSS</td>
        <td>7/5/2014</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

tr > * {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr > th + th {
    width: 70%;
}

tr > th + th + th {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<table>
  <col width="130">
  <col width="80">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_col_width.asp)

Comment: The col width attribute is not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the border attribute, use CSS for all your styling needs.

```
<table style="border:1px; width:100%;">
    <tr>
            <th style="width:15%;">From</th>
            <th style="width:70%;">Subject</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Date</th>
    </tr>
... rest of the table code...
</table>
```

But embedding CSS like that is poor practice - one should use CSS classes instead, and put the CSS rules in an external CSS file.

Comment: I would suspect that the example code the OP and helpful stackoverflowians posted was for legibility and simplicity's sake, by no means an encouragement for inline styles.

Answer (score -2):

```
style="column-width:300px;white-space: normal;"
```

Comment: Hi - welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, answers with text (instead of just code) and some explanation are viewed as better than just code-only answers. Since this question is older and has a lot of other answers, they may help guide you in future answers.