# Using nested forms in Rails - How can I make the show page display every new entry in a table format depending on how many presents the user wants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, nested-forms

I have a baby present registry I'm building with Rails 3.2. There is a registry model and a present model nested under the registry model. Everything works 100% except in the show page.

When a user creates a registry he/she can add presents through the add presents tag  (as many as he/she wants), but the problem is in the show page it only the first present is displayed as I want it too. The rest is displayed in plain non formatted text.

Any help please? I would like it to show in a table format.

Here is my code:
Here is the Registry Form:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@registry) do |f| %>
<% if @registry.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@registry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this registry from    
being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @registry.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>


<%= f.label :due_date %><br />
<%= f.date_select :due_date, :rows => 5 %>


<%= f.label :theme %><br />
<%= f.text_field :theme, :class => 'field2' %>

<div class="field1">
<%= f.label :gender %><br />
<%= f.text_field :gender %>
</div>

<div class="field1">
<%= f.fields_for :presents do |builder| %>
<%= render 'present_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
</div>

<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Presents", f, :presents %>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The presents_fields:

```
<div class="field1">
<table>
<tr> 
<td> <%= f.label :type, "Present Type" %> </td>
<td> <%= f.text_field :type, :class => 'field2' %> </td>
<td> <%= f.label :Quantity, "Quantity" %> </td>
<td> <%= f.number_field :quantity, :class => 'field3' %> </td>
<td> <%= f.label :color, "Color" %> </td>
<td> <%= f.text_field :color, :class => 'field2' %> </td>
<td> <%= f.label :brand, "Brand" %> </td>
<td> <%= f.text_field :brand, :class => 'field2' %> </td>
<td> <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this present" %></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The show page:
    <% provide(:title, 'My Party and Present Whishes') %>
    <%= notice %>

```
<p> Baby & Party Details: </p></br>
<li><p> Due date: </p> <%= @registry.due_date %></li></br>
<li><p> Party Theme: </p><%= @registry.theme %></li></br>
<li><p> Gender: </p><%= @registry.gender %></li></br>

<p> Presents Registry: </p></br>
<li>

<% @registry.presents.each do |registry| %>

<%= registry.type %>
<%= registry.quantity %>
<%= registry.color %>
<%= registry.brand %>

</li>

<% end %>

</br>
</br>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_registry_path(@registry) %>
<%= link_to 'Back', registries_path %>
```

Comment: I believe it's a typo too. You are putting the iteration code inside the <li>, and ending the loop outside the </li>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li>

<% @registry.presents.each do |registry| %>
```

Should not these lines be inverted?

```
<% @registry.presents.each do |registry| %>
<li>
```

Comment: Are you asking about columns width? If so, there are few ways to do it - check for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928849/setting-table-column-width