# TD column width value not working with fixed table-layout

Tags: html, css

I have following table structure:

```
<table class="tableStyle">
<tr>
    <td width="20px">col1</td>
    <td width="50px">col2</td>
    <td width="50px">col3</td>
    <td width="15px">col4</td>
    <td width="25px">col5</td>
    <td width="20px">col6</td>
    <td width="20px">col7</td>
    <td width="20px">col8</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS class definition is:

```
.tableStyle{
table-layout:fixed;
margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;
}
```

The problem is that all columns are displaying with equal width despite the fact that i am explicitly defining each column width.

Why are above width values are not working? Any suggestion to make it work with fixed table layout?

Comment: Hi! I just tried in [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/haxeruya/1/edit) and each column has a different width. Where have you tried your code?

Comment: your code is perfect, td are display with different width

Comment: Do not use the `width` attribute.  It's been deprecated for a _loooong_ time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "archaic" `width` attribute does not take a unit, it expects something like `width="20"`.

However, the "most correct" way to define a table is like so:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:20px" />
        <col style="width:50px" span="2" />
        <col style="width:15px" />
        <col style="width:25px" />
        <col style="width:20px" span="3" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
            <td>col4</td>
            <td>col5</td>
            <td>col6</td>
            <td>col7</td>
            <td>col8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works especially well for large tables, because the browser only needs to read the `<colgroup>` element to know exactly how the entire table should be laid out, without needing to calculate widths based on individual cell styles.

Answer (score 12):

You have to use:

```
<td width="20">
```

or

```
<td style="width: 20px">
```

Answer (score 1):

The width property does not support px for td, if you want to write the width in px, you need to provide css as below

```
<td style="width: 20px">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should the attribute `width` without the unit `px`. Probably there are some modern browsers that accept the attribute with the units, but is not the correct way!

You have a similar issue in this [another Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090544/td-widths-not-working):

Answer (score 0):

Seems like works as intended for me. please check the below fiddle.

```
.tableStyle{
table-layout:fixed;
margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9x56E/

Answer (score 0):

suggest such an option

**HTML**

```
<table class="tableStyle">
<tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
    <td>col4</td>
    <td>col5</td>
    <td>col6</td>
    <td>col7</td>
    <td>col8</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.tableStyle{
table-layout:fixed;
margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;
  background: #ddd;
}
td:nth-child(1n) {
  width: 20px;
  background: #876342;
}
td:nth-child(3n+1) {
  width: 100px;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fFLqG)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the width on the td, try adding it to the th using css.

For example,

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="column-1">Heading 1</th>
        <th class="column-2">Heading 2</th>
        <th class="column-3">Heading 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TD 1</td>
        <td>TD 2</td>
        <td>TD 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.column-1 {
    width: 50%;
}
.column-2 {
    width: 25%;
}
.column-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

I had the exact same problem and found this resource helpful:

https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/