# Why is width on td element not working with table-layout fixed?

Tags: html, css, html4

I have read many post on SO about this, e.g. [TD column width value not working with fixed table-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871179/td-column-width-value-not-working-with-fixed-table-layout?noredirect=1&lq=1) [td widths, not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090544/td-widths-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) etc. But still when I give width to `td` it doesn't get that width. Here is a working example of the problem:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
td:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50px;
}
td:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 400px;">
  <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td class="">
          <a href="#">The_first_line</a>
        </td>
        <td class="">
          <a href="#">The_second_but_a_long_line_with_so_many_characters</a>
        </td>
        <td class="">
          <ul class="">
            <li class=""><a href="#" rel="tag" title="" class="">The simple</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">last</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The first `td` should have taken 50px and the second should have taken 150px, but this is not happening. Why?

Comment: how about use inline css on 2nd `td` and see if it works

Comment: Can be also achieve using `colspan`

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo :second-of-type is invalid. Try :nth-of-type() instead:

```
td:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 150px;
}
```

However this isn't a very robust way of targetting your element. What if you have multiple tables on your page. It might be a good idea to add a class to your table:

```
<table class="my-table">
```

And then target specific for that table:

```
.my-table td:nth-of-type(2) { .. }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such selector like `second-of-type` you can use `nth-child(2)` instead. and you should apply style to `th` while you are using `thead` The below solution gives you the desired result

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
th:first-of-type {
  width: 50px;
}
th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 400px;">
  <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td class="">
          <a href="#">The_first_line</a>
        </td>
        <td class="">
          <a href="#">The_second_but_a_long_line_with_so_many_characters</a>
        </td>
        <td class="">
          <ul class="">
            <li class=""><a href="#" rel="tag" title="" class="">The simple</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">last</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But why do we have to change widths of `th`? I just need to change width of `td`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix width for th instead of td like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/740z1q03/1/)**

```
tr th:first-child {
  width: 50px;
}

tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: But why do we have to change widths of `th`? I just need to change width of `td`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting the width on the td elements, the th are causing the problem. Set the width on both and it will work:

```
td:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50px;
}
th:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50px;
}
tdnth-of-type(2) {
  width: 150px;
}
th:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Example: 
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEAXCBFALXN2