# How to increase the width of table cell using css?

Tags: html, css

Below is the html with embedded css code,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Embedded style</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="max-width:66%;margin:auto;text-align:center;">2008 OFFICERS</h1>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <!-- Tables are surrounded with table tags -->
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;margin:auto;max-width:33%">
            <!-- thead shows at the top of the table and must come before tbody -->
            <thead style="max-width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid black;">Current Officers</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- The main data for the table goes between tbody if you use thead or tfoot -->
            <tbody style="max-width:100%">
                <tr style="max-width:100%">
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">President</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Jesse Blair</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">555-7189</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;max-width:30%">Vice-President</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Frank Smythe</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">505-555-3576</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Secretary</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Jean Darr</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">555-5415</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Treasurer</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Linda Carter</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">555-9653</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <br><br>

        <!-- Tables are surrounded with table tags -->
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;margin:auto;">
            <!-- thead shows at the top of the table and must come before tbody -->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid black;">Board Members at Large</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- The main data for the table goes between tbody if you use thead or tfoot -->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Dick Wilson</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">555-1982</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Jan-Davis</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">555-3530</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am using `max-width` with percentage values for responsive design.

Am suppose to use css properties for any code further.

How do I increase the width of the table cell?

*Note: Inline css is intentionally part of exercise*

Comment: I mean, using the `max-width` property here looks meaningless because if it's specified as percentage, then it will take that % of **containing block's width**. here, you did not specify a `width` property for any element, yet you're using `max-width` attributes?

Comment: Ok, let me put it this way, how about using `<table style="border: 1px solid black;margin:auto;width:33%">` instead of `<table style="border: 1px solid black;margin:auto;max-width:33%">`? isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928849/setting-table-column-width and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090544/td-widths-not-working

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, the *max-width* attribute describes the maximum width the element it applies to can have. If you want to change the width of an element, simply use *width*.

Answer (score 0):

you have set table width to 33% , I think this cause all the problem remove this and width to the  td in percentage.

```
<td width="35%"   style="border: 1px solid black;">President</td>
<td width="30%"   style="border: 1px solid black;">Jesse Blair</td>
<td width="35%" style="border: 1px solid black;">555-7189</td>
```

set width according to your requirement or set using css class and use in code.

Comment: What about screen re-sizing? where horizontal scroll bars come into picture on using `width` property?

Comment: Upto my knowledge if you adjust the body size then the table will also adjust , So if we are giving the td width in percentage then it will also change and adjust in accordance with the body size.