# CSS :hover not working on iOS Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, ios, css, hover

I have a rounded div which has a rounded image and a title at the bottom whith `opacity: 0.5;` On hover the opacity should become 1. It works fine on all desktop browsers and Firefox for iOS but it doesn't work on Safari nor Chrome for iOS.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a10rLbnL/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="video_wrap update">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="img_wrap"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0HDdjwpPM3Y/hqdefault.jpg"></div>
    <div class="title_wrap"><div class="title">bang bang</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video_wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.img_wrap {
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title_wrap {
    line-height: 50px;
    top: -50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #f8008c;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.img_wrap img {
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.title_wrap:hover {opacity: 1}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found a workaround: if you add `onclick=""` to the div, the hover will work.

Your html would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="hover.css" type="text/css"/>

<div class="video_wrap update">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="img_wrap"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0HDdjwpPM3Y/hqdefault.jpg"></div>
    <div class="title_wrap" onclick=""><div class="title">bang bang</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you tap and hold. It's the same as hover and it works in Firefox for iOS.

Comment: You're right. The problem I have when trying to hover in both Chrome and Safari is that I'm selecting the text when I tap and hold on the div. I think Safari puts 'selecting text' before 'applying hover'.

Comment: I found a workaround: if you add `onclick=""` to the div, the hover will work. See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah but you should click at it. it doesn't work if you tap and hold.

Comment: I have a risk like that, but i dont understand why i have two :hover on two <div class=""> different, the first div.class1:hover -> OK on Chrome & Safari Mobile. But the last div.class2:hover -> not working on Safari Mobile, it's only working on Chrome Mobile

Comment: If you add `cursor: pointer` to your CSS it has the same affect.

Comment: You sir just saved my butt with a client project. =)

Answer (score 2):

The iOS Browser needs an element that is clickable by default. If you use HTML5 you can change the wrapper `div` to an `a-tag`:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="title_wrap"><div class="title">bang bang</div></a>`

and set it to an block element:

```
.title_wrap {
  ...
  display:block;
}
```

If you don't use HTML5 you have to change the `<div class="title">` to an inline elment like `<span class="title">` so the code is valid.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

If you want `:hover` and `:focus` to work, use `tabindex="0"`

---

**Explanation:**

The issue is that `<div>` is not, in its natural state, a **focusable** element.

Many elements commonly found in HTML Forms like `<input>` and `<button>` *are* **focusable**, but other elements commonly found outside forms like `<div>` and `<li>` are not.

If you want to make an element **focusable** which, normally, cannot be focused on, there are a number of ways you can achieve this result.

As one answer on this page states, `onclick=""` will make the element **focusable**.

But the ***standard*** way to make an element **focusable** is to use `tabindex="0"`

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 0):

I have the same bag: when hovering over the parent-element, the child-button should change its style from opacity: 0 to opacity: 1  -it does not work only in *Safari*. onclick="" and tabindex="0" - don't work for me.
Strange solution but works!!: add to parent  `position: relative;`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).