# Use a span for showing the elipses instead of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use a span for the overflow of a text.

```css
.jdName {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<td>
    <span className="jdName">Some Name with more characters</span>
</td>
```

Here is the `td` has alreday a fixed width. So, I have not given for the span.

But it is not showing any elipses for this.

I have to use the div for this. Can any one help me how can I use span instead of using a div?

Comment: display:block or inline-block?

Comment: @TemaniAfif  it has to be `display: block`

Comment: @xmaster both accept overflow properties and would work fine (ex: https://jsfiddle.net/euh6n20x/) then it will depend on the code because both will not give the same result.

Comment: @TemaniAfif hmm you are right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-overflow: ellipsis not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993067/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors at play here. First, the `<span>` has inline layout; certain CSS properties don't apply to it by default. And, second, the `<td>` of a `<table>` has its own set of layout quirks.

Normally, if you give the `span` a block layout (set `display` to `inline-block`, `block`, et cetera), and width (of pretty much anything *except* `auto`), the ellipsis would kick in.

`<td>` elements are special cases, though. And *that* is explained better in the SO question [td widths, not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11090559/5796134).

```css
td,
.test-div {
  width: 100px;
}

.jdName {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="jdName">Some Name with more characters</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="test-div">
  <span class="jdName">Some Name with more characters</span>
</div>
```