# Set column width in Tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to set the width for the columns in JQuery Tablesorter. I have an example http://jsfiddle.net/nHWRK/70/ I have 3 columns. I want the whole table to fill the browser window (100%) and dynamical change when the browser window is resized. I want the first column to be 10%, the second column to be 40% and the third column to be 50%, having all three to add up to 100%. I tried to control this in the code by

```
.tablesorter {
    width: 100%;
}
.tablesorter td:nth-child(3n+1) {
    width: 10%;
}
.tablesorter td:nth-child(3n+2) {
    width: 40%;
}
.tablesorter td:nth-child(3n+3) {
    width: 50%;
}
```

At the moment it seems like the first and third column change width dynamically when the window size is changed. But the second column doesn't change. I have a working example here  http://jsfiddle.net/nHWRK/70/embedded/result/. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928849/setting-table-column-width

Answer (score 1):

Set column width with TH and apply below code.

```
$(".GridTable").tablesorter({
    widthFixed: false,
    ........
});
```

This is working for me.