# Table multiple column widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's the code:

```
<table>
<col style="width:10px"><col style="width:20px"><col style="width:30px">
<td>
....
```

which defines three columns of different widths. Is there any way to define CSS layout for whole table - all 3 columns - in one single entry, so that I can write:

```
<table class="cols3">
...
```

and this cols3 class define that this table has 3 columns of predefined width?

Comment: you can do a <div> tag with <ul><li> components in it

Comment: Sorry do not understand - can you elaborate please?

Comment: view answer by Ron DeVera [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928849/setting-table-column-width). It may help you.

Comment: Not really. This model explained I want to eliminate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `nth-child` selector on the child columns, so your css might look like this:

```
.cols3 col:nth-child(1){width:10px;}
.cols3 col:nth-child(2){width:20px;}
.cols3 col:nth-child(3){width:30px;}
```

Be aware that with the nth-child selector, 1 is what is used to get the first child element, not the typical 0.

Comment: Never came across it so far :) and it seems to be supported by all browsers... is it possible to make it in one CSS entry, or 3 entries are required?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need separate entries for each child, but it's not too much work :P

Comment: One small trick: your code will not work unless you have 3 <col> items explicitly defined in the html. I did it easier - removed <col> items, and just wrote "td:nth-child:

Answer (score 1):

In your case with 3 columns try using CSS selectors:

```
table.cols3 col:first-child{
 /* style for first*/
}

table.cols3:last-child{
/*style of last child (3rd column)*/
}

table.cols3 {
/*style for middle columns)*/
}
```

for more selectors (and examples) check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)