# Bootstrap Table Width Sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I always encounter this issue when I'm using Bootstrap for tables.

It seems Bootstrap automatically makes all columns equal width. The issue is something like an email address column gets cut off while a column with just a single digit has more than enough room.

Is there a simple way to get around this (without hacking each individual column?

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your application?

Comment: Its an Angular app so there's jQlite. Ideally I would think this issue could be solved with CSS no?

Comment: I think you assign a class to the email column in your table structure and then make the width bigger in JavaScript as per your width required.

Comment: No need for JS, this question has some good solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928849/setting-table-column-width

Comment: You could attach a Fiddle so we can understand better what you're trying to do...