# How to increase width of a field in html page which has CSS and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

I am new to programming, I have managed to create a page which fetches the data from MySQL.
I have used a jQuery plugin to freeze the first column and first row of my table.
The problem I am facing is, when I try to increase the width of a specific column it is not working.
Please help me to understand how do I increase width for specific column. This is my PHP and CSS for your reference.
Thanks.

## PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title>Region Wise</title>

        <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <header class="header">
            <div class="titulosHeader">
            <h2>Region Wise</h2>

        </header>
    </head>
        <main class="main">
            <div class="ContenedorTabla">


            <?php
    $sql = 'SELECT * from rgn_report';
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    echo "<table id='pruebatabla' class='fht-table hoverTable'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general' rowspan='3' style='height:100px;'>REGION</th>

    <tr>
                            <th class='celda_encabezado_general' colspan='4'>KA</th>
                            <th class='space'></th>
                            <th class='celda_encabezado_general' colspan='4'>MI</th>
                            <th class='space'></th>
                            <th class='celda_encabezado_general' colspan='4'>OT</th>
                            <th class='space'></th>
                            <th class='celda_encabezado_general' colspan='4'>FA</th>
                            <th class='space'></th>
                            <th class='celda_encabezado_general' colspan='4'>HA</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>SOH</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CY</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CT</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>WC</th>
    <th class='space'></th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>SOH</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CY</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CT</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>WC</th>
    <th class='space'></th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>SOH</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CY</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CT</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>WC</th>
    <th class='space'></th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>SOH</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CY</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CT</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>WC</th>
    <th class='space'></th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>SOH</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CY</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>CT</th>
    <th class='celda_encabezado_general'>WC</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rowhighlight = array("RGN1","RGN2","Grand Total");

            if (in_array($row['rgn'],$rowhighlight)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . $row['rgn']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['KA_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['KA_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['KA_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . $row['KA_CVR']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='space'></td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['MI_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['MI_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['MI_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . $row['MI_CVR']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='space'></td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['OT_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['OT_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['OT_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . $row['OT_CVR']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='space'></td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['FA_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['FA_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['FA_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . $row['FA_CVR']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='space'></td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['HA_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['HA_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . number_format($row['HA_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='highlight_cell'>" . $row['HA_CVR']."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";}
        else
        {
            echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . $row['rgn']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['KA_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['KA_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['KA_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . $row['KA_CVR']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='space'></td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['MI_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['MI_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['MI_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . $row['MI_CVR']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='space'></td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['OT_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['OT_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['OT_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . $row['OT_CVR']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='space'></td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['FA_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['FA_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['FA_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . $row['FA_CVR']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='space'></td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['HA_SOH'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['HA_CY'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . number_format($row['HA_CT'])."</td>";
    echo "<td class='excel_cell'>" . $row['HA_CVR']."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    echo "</tbody>";

    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    </div>
    </main>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.CongelarFilaColumna.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#pruebatabla").CongelarFilaColumna({Columnas:1});

            });
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

## CSS

```
        *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border:0;

        }

    .header, .main {
        display: inline-block;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;

    }
    .titulosHeader {

        height: auto;


    }
    .ContenedorTabla {
        height: 540px;
        border: 1px solid green;
        overflow: auto; 
        position: relative;
        max-width:auto;
    }
    .fht-table,
    .fht-table thead,
    .fht-table tfoot,
    .fht-table tbody,
    .fht-table tr,
    .fht-table th,
    .fht-table td 
    {
        margin: 0;

    }

    .fht-table{
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 0 none;
        table-layout:fixed;

    }

    .fht-table th,.fht-table td {
        overflow: hidden;

        table-layout:fixed;

    }

    .fht-table-wrapper,
    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-thead,
    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-tfoot,
    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-fixed-column .fht-tbody,
    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-fixed-body .fht-tbody,
    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-tbody {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;

    }

    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-fixed-body .fht-tbody,
    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-tbody {
        overflow: auto;

    }

    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-table .fht-cell {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 1px;

    }

    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-fixed-column,
    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-fixed-body {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .fht-table-wrapper .fht-fixed-column {
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .fht-fixed-body .fht-thead table {
        margin-right: 20px;
        border: 0 none;
    }
    .celda_encabezado_general {
        background-color: #4BACC6;
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
        white-space: nowrap;

        }

    ._Separador{
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 12px;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 7px;
    }
    ._Separador div{
        width: 4px;
    }
    .celda_normal {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 2px 4px;
    }


    .excel_cell{
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: #222;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight:  normal;
        padding: 5px;
        empty-cells: show;
        font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
        white-space: nowrap;

    }
    ._cell_header{
        background-color: #EEE;
    }
    ._cell_Default{
        background-color: #FFF;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .excel_cell div{
        width: 30px;
        height: 20px;
    }


    .highlight_cell{
        border: 2px solid black;
        color: #222;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight:  bold;
        padding: 5px;
        empty-cells: show;
        font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

        .hoverTable tr:hover {
        background-color: grey; 
        }




    .space{
        border: none;
        empty-cells: show;
        background-color:grey;
        width:10px;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/928849/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B ,thanks for the link. i had gone through the solutions but could not get it work. im not able to find out how the width setting is controlled in my page.

Comment: If you can post a working demo maybe we can help you some more. When the problem can't be reproduced it's more of a guessing game.