# I can't set the width of the columns of my table

Tags: html, css, html-table

In order to set the width of my columns, I try to do the solution posted here :
[Setting table column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928849/setting-table-column-width)

Like this :

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>0h-1h</th>
    <th>1h-2h</th>
    <th>2h-3h</th>
    <th>3h-4h</th>
    <th>4h-5h</th>
    <th>5h-6h</th>
    <th>6h-7h</th>
    <th>7h-8h</th>
    <th>8h-9h</th>
    <th>9h-10h</th>
    <th>10h-11h</th>
    <th>11h-12h</th>
    <th>12h-13h</th>
    <th>13h-14h</th>
    <th>14h-15h</th>
    <th>15h-16h</th>
    <th>16h-17h</th>
    <th>17h-18h</th>
    <th>18h-19h</th>
    <th>19h-20h</th>
    <th>20h-21h</th>
    <th>21h-22h</th>
    <th>22h-23h</th>
    <th>23h-0h</th>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Lundi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Mardi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Mercredi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Jeudi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Vendredi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Samedi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Dimanche</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Why it doesn't work ?

I just want 25 equals columns (in width), but the parameters seems to have no effects....

On my site, I can't scroll in order to access all the columns (grid in material design),
and I want all the table in screen.

Comment: Have you set `table {table-layout: fixed}` in css?

Comment: Nothing like this in the style.css file.

Is it the default parameters for table ?

Comment: No, it's not default, it's what you need to have it working

Comment: I add it, nothing changed.

Comment: Yes it is html5 (cf. <!DOCTYPE html> )

Comment: I try it :
https://jsfiddle.net/simongirard1991/ukhjseaf/
It is not working.

Comment: Why are you doing the styling inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width:100%` to your inputs solves the problem. See link below:

```css
input{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>0h-1h</th>
    <th>1h-2h</th>
    <th>2h-3h</th>
    <th>3h-4h</th>
    <th>4h-5h</th>
    <th>5h-6h</th>
    <th>6h-7h</th>
    <th>7h-8h</th>
    <th>8h-9h</th>
    <th>9h-10h</th>
    <th>10h-11h</th>
    <th>11h-12h</th>
    <th>12h-13h</th>
    <th>13h-14h</th>
    <th>14h-15h</th>
    <th>15h-16h</th>
    <th>16h-17h</th>
    <th>17h-18h</th>
    <th>18h-19h</th>
    <th>19h-20h</th>
    <th>20h-21h</th>
    <th>21h-22h</th>
    <th>22h-23h</th>
    <th>23h-0h</th>
      <tr>
        <th>Lundi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Mardi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Mercredi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Jeudi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Vendredi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Samedi</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Dimanche</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" step="1"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a specific width in table according to size of your div.

add style as below

```
  <table style="width:350px; overflow-x:scroll;">

  //.... 
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<col span="1" style="width: 4%;">
```

to

```
<col width="4%">
```

It will work