Access VBA create a new table in an email when the field changes
I'm having a hard time getting a formatted table into an email through Access VBA. I can get it to create one giant table for everything in the recordset, but I need one table for each check number (a field in the record set). Any ideas?
I've tried so many variations of code - I thought I might need the arow in arow(1-9) to be dynamic, but I can't figure that piece out.
Here's what I have to make the one giant table:
Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olItem As Variant
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strQry As String
    Dim aHead(1 To 8) As String
    Dim aRow(1 To 8) As String
    Dim aBody() As String
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim strpicpath As String
    Dim appoutlook As Outlook.Application: Set appoutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Dim mimEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set mimEmail = appoutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    


  
'strpicpath = "path"


    'Create the header row
    aHead(1) = "End Debtor Name"
    aHead(2) = "Invoice"
    aHead(3) = "Check Number"
    aHead(4) = "Exception Type"
    aHead(5) = "Amount"
    aHead(6) = "Actions to Resolve"
    aHead(7) = "Notes"
    aHead(8) = "Client Response"


    lCnt = 1
    ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
    aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

    'Create each body row
    strQry = "SELECT * From tbl_SendEmailsTemp"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
        Do While Not rec.EOF
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
            aRow(1) = rec("EndDebtor Name")
            aRow(2) = rec("Invoice #")
            aRow(3) = rec("Check Number1")
            aRow(4) = rec("Exception Type")
            aRow(5) = rec("Balance")
            aRow(6) = rec("Notes")
            aRow(7) = ""
            aRow(8) = ""
            aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
            rec.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

    'create the email
With mimEmail

       .To = "test"
    '.To = ContactEmail & ";" & ContactEmail2 & ";" & ContactEmail3
    '.cc = creditrep & ";" & "credit "
    .Subject = Client_Name & ", Exceptions Report, " & Date - 1
    Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
    Set att = .Attachments.Add(strpicpath, 1, 0)
    .HTMLBody = "<img src=""Exceptions.png""><br><br><br>" _
                       & "<BODY style = font-size: 11pt>Please see below for the exceptions generated from " & Date - 1 & " transactions. All applicable back-up documentation is attached:</BODY><br><br>" _
                       & Join(aBody, vbNewLine) & " <br><br>"
                       
    .Display

End With

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_AppendEmailed"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_AppendNotEmailed"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_DeleteFromExceptions"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub


HTML only has one <body> element....   Is your data sorted by check number?

You can use a single recordset, as long as you order by check number (untested):
Sub tester()
    
    Const olMailItem As Long = 0 'late binding so need this Outlook constant
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strQry As String
    Dim headers, widths, checkNo, currCheckNo, tableHTML As String, tblStart As String, rowInfo
    Dim strpicpath As String
    Dim appoutlook As Object, mimEmail As Object
    
    headers = Array("End Debtor Name", "Invoice", "Check Number", "Exception Type", _
                "Amount", "Actions to Resolve", "Notes", "Client Response")

    widths = Array("100px", "120px", "80px", "130px", _
                   "200px", "100px", "50px", "90px")
    
    tblStart = "<table border='2'>" & TableRow("th", headers, widths)
    
    'query is ordered by check number
    strQry = "SELECT * From tbl_SendEmailsTemp order by [Check Number1]"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)
    currCheckNo = Chr(0)
    tableHTML = ""
    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
        Do While Not rec.EOF
            checkNo = rec("Check Number1").Value
            If checkNo <> currCheckNo Then 'start new table?
                'close off previous table?
                If Len(tableHTML) > 0 Then tableHTML = tableHTML & "</table>"
                tableHTML = tableHTML & tblStart 'start new table
                currCheckNo = checkNo
            End If
            
            rowInfo = Array(rec("EndDebtor Name"), rec("Invoice #"), _
                            checkNo, rec("Exception Type"), _
                            rec("Balance"), rec("Notes"), "", "")
            
            tableHTML = tableHTML & TableRow("td", rowInfo)
               
            rec.MoveNext
        Loop
        tableHTML = tableHTML & "</table>" 'close off last table
    End If

    'create the email
    Set appoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mimEmail = appoutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With mimEmail
        .To = "test"
        '.To = ContactEmail & ";" & ContactEmail2 & ";" & ContactEmail3
        '.cc = creditrep & ";" & "credit "
        .Subject = Client_Name & ", Exceptions Report, " & Date - 1
        Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
        Set att = .Attachments.Add(strpicpath, 1, 0)
        .HTMLBody = "<html><body style='font-size: 11pt'><img src='Exceptions.png'><br><br><br>" _
            & "Please see below for the exceptions generated from " & Date - 1 & _
            " transactions. All applicable back-up documentation is attached:<br><br>" _
            & tableHTML & "<br><br></body></html>"
                           
        .Display
    End With

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_AppendEmailed"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_AppendNotEmailed"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_DeleteFromExceptions"
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub


'Given an array of values, create an HTML table header or body row
'  optionally provide an array of widths for each column
Function TableRow(cellType As String, arrTexts, Optional arrWidths) As String
    Dim el As String, w As String, html As String, i As Long
    html = "<tr>"
    For i = LBound(arrTexts) To UBound(arrTexts)
        el = arrTexts(i)
        If Not IsMissing(arrWidths) Then w = " style=""width:" & arrWidths(i) & """"
        html = html & "<" & cellType & w & ">" & el & "</" & cellType & ">"
    Next i
    TableRow = html & "</tr>"
End Function


Wow - thank you so much for this! I appreciate it more than you know!

Any idea how to get the column widths set? I've tried throwing in some HTML, but no luck.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/928859/478884.  You can have an array of column widths and you'll need to swap out the Join for a loop.

See updates above.  Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

Lifesaver! Thanks again!!!

You need an outer recordset that loops the Check numbers. Use GROUP BY for this.
And for each iteration of the outer loop, open an inner recordset that creates the table for that number.
Something like:
sNumber = "SELECT [Check Number1] AS CurrentNumber From tbl_SendEmailsTemp GROUP BY [Check Number1]"
Set recNumber = db.OpenRecordset(sNumber)

Do While Not recNumber.EOF
    ' assuming [Check Number1] is a number
    lNumber = recNumber!CurrentNumber
    
    ' Now select only the rows for that number
    strQry = "SELECT * From tbl_SendEmailsTemp WHERE [Check Number1] = " & lNumber
    
    ' Then proceed creating the table with the code you have already 
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset(strQry)
    ' ... etc.
    
    ' append this table (perhaps with a heading for [Check Number1]) to a string variable for the HTML body 
    
    recNumber.MoveNext
Loop

' Now create the email, using the body you built above

As Tim writes, the <HTML> and <body> tags need to go outside of both loops. They belong to the final step.

Thank you for taking the time to help me with this!!
